# Check which option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When a button is clicked, I am using AJAX to display a PHP modal, with a form inside it. It is an edit form so the fields are filled in with data received from AJAX calling a PHP function via a handler. However I need a way for a `select` input to know which one is selected but, the data to use for that is in JavaScript. Usually I would use a function such as

```
$occasionTypes = getPublishedOccasionTypes($connection);
if($occasionTypes != NULL){
    foreach ($occasionTypes as $occasionType) {
        $selected = (isset($booking['reservation_type']) && ($booking['reservation_type'] == $occasionType['id'])) ? 'selected' : NULL;
        $occasionSelect .= '<option value='.$occasionType['id'].' '.$selected.'>'.$occasionType['name'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

But in this case, `$booking['reservation_type]` is useless because the actual value I need is in an input (a hidden one I created) but being filled by JavaScript. Anyone any ideas? Here is my JavaScript also

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
    data: data
})
.done((result)=>{
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(result);
    
    $('#firstName').val(result.customer_first_name);
    $('#lastName').val(result.customer_last_name);
    $('#email').val(result.customer_email);
    $('#number').val(result.customer_mobile);
    $('#date').val(result.reservation_date);
    $('#time').val(result.reservation_time);
    $('#size').val(result.party_size);
    $('#occasion').val(result.occasion_type);
    $('#comment').val(result.special_requirements);
    $('#code').val(pcode);
    $('#customerCode').val(result.customer_code);
    
    $('#editModal').modal('show');
    
})
```

MODAL

```
$modalpopup =
'
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Booking</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>

            <form id="editBooking" class="form form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Time</label>
            <select id="time" name="time" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <option value="">Please select ...</option>
                                                        '.$timeSelect.'
                                                    </select>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Party Size</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="size" id="size" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Occasion</label>
            <select id="occasion" name="occasion" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
                                                        '.$occasionSelect.'
                                                    </select>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status" placeholder="">
              <option value="accepted">Accepted</option>
              <option value="not-accepted">Not Accepted</option>
            </select>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Comment</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder=""></textarea>
                    </div>

          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="customerCode" id="customerCode" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning, the hidden input is only filled when i click the button to make the modal appear.

Comment: Does the `select` element already exist on your page? You just need to figure out which option is selected?

Comment: Can you show html ? also where is hidden field ?

Comment: Yes exactly. The AJAX returns an Id, and in the PHP code about I would normally use that id to find out row in which the id corresponds

Comment: I edited the question to show the modal

Comment: @TiernO Your question is somewhat unclear, you are already setting the value of that dropdown in your ajax success `$('#occasion').val(result.occasion_type);` - receiving the selected value will just give you `result.occasion_type`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton When I make the modal appear, id like for the select input to already be showing the one that is selected. The `result.occasion_type` returns an ID. That's why in the question I need to run `getPublishedOccasionTypes` so I can get the name of it, based on the id

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Basically I need a way to use `result.occasion_type` in that php function

Comment: @TiernO OH, you want the TEXT value of the select? In this case, just do `$("#occasion option:selected").text();` after setting the value.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, which is in a different table, than the table I retrieved the Id from

Comment: @TiernO But the text value is already stored in the select option, right? If you need to fetch any data from the table, you can't do that in the javascript itself, you'll need to do that during the ajax request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217904/discussion-between-tierno-and-grumpycrouton).